# Convert path to UNC path

Tags: c#, unc

I have tried this code to convert my path to UNC path:

```
[DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
static extern int WNetGetUniversalName(
    string lpLocalPath,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwInfoLevel,
    IntPtr lpBuffer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int lpBufferSize);

const int UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL = 0x00000001;
const int REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL = 0x00000002;

const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
const int NOERROR = 0;    

static string GetUniversalName(string localPath)
{
    // The return value.
    string retVal = null ;

    // The pointer in memory to the structure.
    IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

    // Wrap in a try/catch block for cleanup.
    try
    {
        // First, call WNetGetUniversalName to get the size.
        int size = 0;

        // Make the call.
        // Pass IntPtr.Size because the API doesn't like null, even though
        // size is zero.  We know that IntPtr.Size will be
        // aligned correctly.
        int apiRetVal = WNetGetUniversalName(localPath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, (IntPtr) IntPtr.Size, ref size);

        // If the return value is not ERROR_MORE_DATA, then
        // raise an exception.
        if (apiRetVal != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            // Throw an exception.
            throw new Win32Exception(apiRetVal);

        // Allocate the memory.
        buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

        // Now make the call.
        apiRetVal = WNetGetUniversalName(localPath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, buffer, ref size);

        // If it didn't succeed, then throw.
        if (apiRetVal != NOERROR)
            // Throw an exception.
            throw new Win32Exception(apiRetVal);

        // Now get the string.  It's all in the same buffer, but
        // the pointer is first, so offset the pointer by IntPtr.Size
        // and pass to PtrToStringAnsi.
        retVal = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size), size);
        retVal = retVal.Substring(0, retVal.IndexOf('\0'));
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the buffer.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
    }

    // First, allocate the memory for the structure.

    // That's all folks.
    return retVal;
}
```

But when I send the path `\\myservername\sharedfoldername` to this method i receive this error:

> The specified device name is not valid.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Seems a bit unfair voting this post down... the guy just didn't know how to use this code and asked for help like everyone else on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The WNetGetUniversalName function *takes a drive-based path* for a network resource and returns an information structure that contains a more universal form of the name.

You're passing in a UNC path, but the function expects a *drive-based* path (i.e. something like `X:\foo\bar`) and will then *return* a UNC path.

Comment: thanks, so what should i do to get the UNC path of my path?Is there any method?

Comment: I don't understand your question... `\\myservername\sharedfoldername` *is* a UNC path. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have a file in this path and i want to open it in autocad but i received this error : "File \\servername\sharedfoldername\protectedfoldername\File1.dwg" is not found.some one told me to convert my path to UNC version.Please help me?

Comment: Well, a path like `\\servername\sharedfoldername\...` **is** in UNC format... You might actually try the reverse: map a drive letter to that share, and then see if AutoCAD can open  `X:\protectedfoldername\File1.dwg`.

Answer (score 1):

> The specified device name is not valid.

As far as I can remember, when WNetGetUniversalName() got the path of local drive, it also returned ERROR_BAD_DEVICE_PATH.

So, three years ago, I understood this return code as below;

> ERROR_BAD_DEVICE_PATH :
>    Please check whether the path is really needed to change into UNC name or not.